# Glob function (c) and backup file (file~)

Tags: c, glob

I'm using glob function for a autocompletion function. I'm showing you the problem because it's difficult to explain:

```
matched = ~/.tcsh
glob(matched, 0, NULL, &pglob);
```

glob put all matched files in a char ** and when I print it I have:

```
case[0] = .tcshrc
case[1] =
```

I should have `.tcshrc~` in case[1], but nothing =S, I've seen a flag "GLOB_TILDE" like this "

```
 glob(matched, GLOB_TILDE, NULL, &pglob);
```

But it doesn't change anything! Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you sure you want this question tagged with the C# tag?

Comment: This question is confusing at best. What is `case[0]`?

Answer (score 1):

The `GLOB_TILDE` flag only affects the output when the ~ appears at the beginning of the glob.  See here:

http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/More-Flags-for-Globbing.html

As for your problem, it appears to me that your matched value is wrong.  Seems like you should be sticking a `*` at the end of it for it to be useful for autocompletion, i.e.:

```
matched = ~/.tcsh*
```

I'm a little bit confused as how your previous example found even the first one.  The bottom part of this man page article has some interesting examples too:

http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/glob.html